# Longtable and inserting pagebreak / newline depending the row index

Tags: tables, longtable, conditionals, etoolbox

I'm having troubles to find a solution to understand what is wrong in the below code in the last line of the `row` macro, specifically the with the code `\xifinlist{\arabic{currow}}{\rowpagebreaks}{\pagebreak}{}`. What I want to achieve is that if a row index (stored in `currow`) is in a list of row indexes that require to start at a new page (stored in `rowpagebreaks`), results in inserting a `\pagebreak` so that longtable knows to start with this specific row at a blank page. While hardcoding `\pagebreak` works as expected, using a conditional for inserting `\pagebreak` provides me the following error messages that I'm not able to interpret in a meaningful way:

```
Misplaced \noalign.
\pagebreak ->\noalign 
                      {\ifnum `}=0\fi \@testopt {\LT@no@pgbk -}4
l.85     \row{\datespan{11/2008}{03/2013}}{b}
                                             %
I expect to see \noalign only after the \cr of
an alignment. Proceed, and I'll ignore this case.
 main.tex, line 88
Misplaced \omit.
\multispan ->\omit 
                   \@multispan 
l.88     \rowsection{Section B}
                               %
I expect to see \omit only after tab marks or the \cr of
an alignment. Proceed, and I'll ignore this case.
```

My question would be why inserting/hardcoding `\pagebreak` works just fine but using a conditional triggers that kind of error? Is there any solution to this kind of error and situation?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\setlength{\tabcolsep}{0pt}

% counting the rows
\newcounter{currow}

\newlength{\rowmargin}
\setlength{\rowmargin}{15pt}

\newtoggle{addrowmargin}
\togglefalse{addrowmargin}

\newtoggle{debug}
\togglefalse{debug}

% a list of row indexes when a pagebreak should be inserted
\newcommand*\rowpagebreaks{}
\forcsvlist{\listadd\rowpagebreaks}{3,6}

\newcommand{\row}[2]{%
    \iftoggle{debug}{%
        {\scriptsize\textbf{Row: \arabic{currow}}\newline}%
    }{}%
    %
    {#1} & {#2}%
    %
    \stepcounter{currow}%
    %
    \tabularnewline%
    % If the index of the current row is found in the list of rows that require to start at a new blank page, insert a \pagebreak or \newpage ...
    %
    % Manually inserting \pagebreak or \newpage works
    %\pagebreak
    %\newpage   
    % However, this does not work ...
    \xifinlist{\arabic{currow}}{\rowpagebreaks}{\pagebreak}{}%
}

\newcommand{\rowsection}[1]{%
    \rowspan{%
        \begin{minipage}[t]{\columnwidth}%
            \vspace{20pt}% top section margin
            {\normalfont\sffamily\footnotesize #1 \par}%
            \vspace{-\baselineskip}%
            \vspace{6pt}% margin between text and line
            \rule{\linewidth}{.5pt}%
            \vspace{12pt}% bottom section margin
        \end{minipage}%
    }%
    % reset row counter to zero
    \stepcounter{currow}%
    \togglefalse{addrowmargin}%
    %
    \tabularnewline%
    \hline%
}

\newcommand{\rowspan}[1]{%
    % no indent of column
    \multicolumn{2}{@{}l@{}}{%
        \iftoggle{debug}{%
            {\scriptsize\textbf{Row: \arabic{currow}}~ }%
        }{}%
        #1%
    }%
}

\newcommand{\colwidth}[1]{%
    \dimexpr #1\textwidth-2\tabcolsep%
}%

\newcommand{\datespan}[2]{%
    \begin{minipage}[t]{\colwidth{.23}}#1\hfill-\hfill#2\end{minipage}%
}%

\begin{document}

\begin{longtable}{@{}p{\colwidth{.25}}p{\colwidth{.75}}@{}}%
    \rowsection{Section A}%
    \row{\datespan{11/2008}{03/2013}}{b}%
    \row{\datespan{11/2008}{03/2013}}{b}%
    \row{a}{b}%
    \row{a}{b}%
    \rowsection{Section B}%
    \row{\datespan{11/2008}{03/2013}}{b}%
    \row{\datespan{11/2008}{03/2013}}{b}%
    \row{a}{b}%
    \row{a}{b}%
\end{longtable}%

\end{document}
```

Comment: I'm getting an error thrown even if the `\xifinlist` does nothing, so I'm not sure the page break is to blame - it seems like it's the presence of a conditional after the `\tabularnewline`. A fix seems to be `\xifinlist{\arabic{currow}}{\rowpagebreaks}{\tabularnewline\pagebreak}{\tabularnewline}%` but I can't help as to why.

Comment: like `\multicolumn` a page break has to be the first thing (after expansion) in a table row, once you have started the first cell it is too late. So any tests that you do have to work by expansion only. You can not do any definitions, or increment any counters for example unless you do them in `\noalign`

Comment: @DaiBowen Thank you for solution. Taking my original code your suggestion works perfectly fine. I never have thought about this solution ....

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Thank you, as always, for your nice explanation. It once more reminds me to look deeper into how expansion really works. Very helpful comments!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think that \xifinlist is expandable. You could perhaps do the test with expl3 but normally it is simply easier to move the test in the cell before:

```
\newcommand\conditionalpagebreak{}
\newcommand{\row}[2]{%
    \iftoggle{debug}{%
        {\scriptsize\textbf{Row: \arabic{currow}}\newline}%
    }{}%
    %
    {#1} & {#2}%
    %
    \stepcounter{currow}%
    %
    \xifinlist{\arabic{currow}}{\rowpagebreaks} 
        {\global\let\conditionalpagebreak\pagebreak}
        {\gdef\conditionalpagebreak{}}%
    \tabularnewline
    \conditionalpagebreak
}
```

Comment: Thank you Ulrike for taking the time to look into this issue. If I understood it right, if the conditional is true it defines a global variable that contains a "\pagebreak", if false the global variable is emptied. I generally have troubles understanding expansion but does it work because the the conditional is expanded (processed and calculated) before the "\tabularnewline" command and can be therefore inserted after the "\tabularnewline" command? Anyway, thank's so much for your help!

Comment: Yes, the conditional is calculated at the end of the cell before and then stored in a simple, expandable command which you can safely use after \tabularnewline. Be aware that you can run into problems if the cell is part of some \multicolumn.